# Entity Framework - Connection string - Keyword not supported 'Data Source'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, connection-string

I know this is a common issue faced by beginners in EF and there have been multiple questions and answers on the same here, but still I have not been able to still resolve the issue.

I am using EF 4.1 and MVC 3 and have generated the EF model from the DB in a separate library. I have copied the connection string from the app.config in the supporting library to the web.config of my application. I am also instantiating the object context by passing the web.config connection string.

```
string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MasterDataContainer"].ConnectionString;

context = new MasterDataContainer(connectionString);
```

The connection string in web.config is as below

```
<connectionStrings>    
    <add name="MasterDataContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MasterData.csdl|res://*/MasterData.ssdl|res://*/MasterData.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MasterData;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I am getting the error "Keyword not supported : data source".
Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `EntityConnectionStringBuilder` since you already have an EF connection string. i.e. just

```
string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MasterDataContainer"].ConnectionString;
context = new MasterDataContainer(connectionString);
```

`EntityConnectionStringBuilder` can be used to build up an EF connection from e.g. a vanilla .NET one.

**Edit**
It looks like you've encountered this problem [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2008/12/09/explicit-connection-string-for-ef.aspx). The workaround is to escape the load the connection string and then replace the `&quot;` with `"'"`

What might be easier altogether is to use the [`name=ConnStringName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb739017.aspx) overload of ObjectContext / DbContext. In your case, this would be

```
context = new MasterDataContainer("name=MasterDataContainer");
```

Note also if you view the source of the generated Context (probably `MasterDataContainer.Context.cs`) that the default constructor should have the EntityContainerName property hardcoded into it, so you might not need to provide a connectionstring at all to the constructor, provided that you keep the same EntityContainerName.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb739017.aspx

Comment: Thanks fot pointing that out. I have updated the code, but the primary issue still persists.

Comment: @Klaas I've done a bit more homework - hopefully one of these suggestions will help.

Comment: It turns out I had kept the providerName as SqlClient in web.config all along (I had copied the connection string from app.config thinking that I had pasted the exact same thing in web.config). Now I have corrected that and it works. My Bad!. Thanks a lot for those suggestions, especially the EntityContainerName. Didn't know that till now.

Answer (score 0):

easiest way to solve this issue is rewrite your EF conn string (replacing the *amp;* and *quot;*):

from ORIGINAL

```
<add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityModel.csdl|res://*/EntityModel.ssdl|res://*/EntityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;metadata=res://*/EntityModel.csdl|res://*/EntityModel.ssdl|res://*/EntityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&amp;quot;data source=<SERVER\INSTANCE>;initial catalog=<BDD>;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&amp;quot;&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

to FIXED

```
<add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityModel.csdl|res://*/EntityModel.ssdl|res://*/EntityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='metadata=res://*/EntityModel.csdl|res://*/EntityModel.ssdl|res://*/EntityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient';provider connection string='data source=<SERVER\INSTANCE>;initial catalog=<BDD>;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Just change then **Entities** name and the tags **SERVER\INSTANCE** and **BDD** with your values and that's it.

I hope this saves you a few days of research. Enjoy!